# How to create DataFrame with nulls using toDF?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How do you create a dataframe containing nulls from a sequence using .toDF ?

This works:

```
val df = Seq((1,"a"),(2,"b")).toDF("number","letter")
```

but I'd like to do something along the lines of:

```
val df = Seq((1, NULL),(2,"b")).toDF("number","letter")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NULL` is not defined in `API`s anywhere but `null` is, so you can define like

```
val df2 = Seq((1, null), (2, "b")).toDF("number","letter")
```

And you should have output as

```
+------+------+
|number|letter|
+------+------+
|1     |null  |
|2     |b     |
+------+------+
```

The trick is to use two or more values for the column with nulls to define a type Spark SQL should use.

The following then won't work:

```
val df = Seq((1, null)).toDF("number","letter")
```

Spark has no way of knowing what the type of letter is in this case.

Comment: Follow up (may post as another question but would be good to get incorporated into here): Why does val df = Seq((1, null), (2, "1")).toDF("field1","field2") work but val df = Seq((1, null), (2, 1)).toDF("field1","field2") not work?

Comment: @user2682459, its because a dataframe would need schema of constant datatype for each column. null is of stringType and 1 is of integerType. They don't match for field2 datatype.

Comment: ok, so how can you make a dataframe with a null/missing numeric value?

Comment: null can not be used I guess. If you define as `val df = Seq((1, null.asInstanceOf[Int]), (2, 1)).toDF("field1","field2")` null value is converted to 0. so either you define field2 as stringType or replace null with 0

Comment: It's actually _can_ be done for numbers as well as any other type in Spark. The simplest way is to use case classes. E.g. `case class MyRow(x: Integer, y:Integer)`. And then `Seq(MyRow(null, null)).toDF` will produce you exactly what you expect - nullable integers.

Comment: @AlexVayda go ahead and answer it as a separate answer. other people will get benefited

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Ramesh's answer it's worth noting that since `toDF` uses reflection to infer the schema it's important for the provided sequence to have a correct type. And if scala's type inference isn't enough you need to specify the type explicitly.

For example if you want 2nd column to be nullable integer then neither of the following works:

`Seq((1, null))` has inferred  type `Seq[(Int, Null)]`

`Seq((1, null), (2, 2))` has inferred type `Seq[(Int, Any)]`

In this case you need to explicitly specify the type for the 2nd column. There are at least two ways how to do it. You can explicitly specify the generic type for the sequence

```
Seq[(Int, Integer)]((1, null)).toDF
```

or create a case class for the row:

```
case class MyRow(x: Int, y: Integer)
Seq(MyRow(1, null)).toDF
```

Note that I used `Integer` instead of `Int` as the later being a primitive type cannot accommodate nulls.